# 'AuthDataResult' has no member uid error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a new user within my firebase database, and I'm trying to set some more values to the user: name, email, password, DOB, etc.

```
/* Create User with Email and Password Provided */
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        /* Handle errors that may occur while Creating user in Firebase */
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

            }
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
            self.signUpButton.isEnabled = true
            return
        } else {

            SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading")
            let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
            let userRef = rootRef.child("users").child(user!.uid)
```

The error occurs within the completion block as I'm trying to access the child(user!.uid). I want to be able to set values to it such as:

```
rootRef.userRef.child("name").setValue(self.nameTextfield.text!)
```

but I can't since there must be an issue with the Callback when I'm accessing the (user) parameter. Xcode states 'AuthDataResult' has no member uid.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Roberto,

'user' in your completion handler is of type AuthDataResult? and not of type User?. However, AuthDataResult can be used to access information of a *signed in user*. To access the UID in your scenario above, simply apply this:

```
user?.user.uid
```

which should look like this when applied:

```
let userRef = rootRef.child("users").child(user?.user.uid)
```

Here you are taking the AuthDataResult 'user' and accessing it's member ('user'), which is finally of type User?. Then we are simply just accessing the User type's UID like we regularly would.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error message talks about [`AuthDataResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult), it seems you have to do:

```
let userRef = rootRef.child("users").child(user!.user!.uid)
```

I'd also recommend you check out the [Firebase guide on creating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account).

Comment: Frank, where in the Firebase guide can I find this solution you provided? I can't find it under create a new user, nor the Database reference guides. Also, I am getting the same error while using your solutions.

Comment: It's under step 4 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#create_a_password_based_account. I noticed the parameter is called `authResult` there, so that it likely matches with https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult, which then in turn has a `user` property https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult#user

Comment: A little bit annoying that Firebase engineers changed the type property   `user`. The of type used to be `FIRUser`. Now, the type is `User`. As a consequence I have to rename my custom model class since it's of type User and conflicts with Firebase User type.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct form

```
@IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any){
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text{
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:
            {(user,error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if let user = user {
                        self.userUid = user.user.uid
                        self.goToCreateUserVC()
                    }
                }

        });
    }
}
```

This is the incorrect form:

```
@IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any){
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text{
        Auth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:
            {(user,error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if let user = user {
                        self.userUid = user.uid
                        self.goToCreateUserVC()
                    }
                }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As most people already said, it would be something like this:

```
user?.user.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

buddy just reference the firebase user like this;

var user: Firebase.User?

at the top of your view controller

Comment: the above(FRANKS ANSWER) answer will nest the uid which will be a headache to reference later, nesting is NOT considered as efficient database code as Firebase is not SQL but a HTML retrieval system where you don't need to nest to get the users data, that's why you have the option childByAutoID()